# Exception not marked as serializable

Tags: .net, exception, serialization

With no changes to code (that I recall) formatter.Serialize fails for on type of object
It works for 5 other types tested
I have made no changes to that class (that I recall) - is is marked as Serializable 
It is a fairly simple class and has no reverence to a system.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument

How can I tack down the error and fix it?

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        try
        {
            formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(Ex.Source);
```

A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Type 'System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument' in Assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

InnerExeption is null

I have some what narrow it down and prior to a call to a property it works
After a call to that property it fails
ThisUserGroups is the property

```
try
{
    User userclone = DeepClone<User>(CurUser);   // success
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Before call to CurUser.ThisUserGroups.Count()");
    Debug.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
}
Debug.WriteLine("CurUser.ThisUserGroups.Count()" + " " + CurUser.ThisUserGroups.Count() + " " + CurUser.UserID);
try
{
    User userclone = DeepClone<User>(CurUser);  //failure 
}
```

Problem class and property
Other properties and methods omitted
Group is Serializable

```
[Serializable()]
public class User : Object, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [field: NonSerializedAttribute()]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    private HashSet<Group> thisUserGroups;
    public HashSet<Group> ThisUserGroups
    {   // after a call to this deepclone fails  
        get
        {
            if (thisUserGroups == null)
            {
                thisUserGroups = new HashSet<Group>();
                foreach (Group g in groupsPlus)  // static all groups in library 14
                {
                    if (!thisUserGroups.Contains(g) && g.ID <= 0) 
                        thisUserGroups.Add(g);
                }
                foreach (UserGroup userGroup in userGroups.OrderBy(x => x.Group.Name))  // docAdmin  fail userGroups == 54 and thisUserGoups is 2
                {                                                                       // docAdminNotGroup success userGroups == 54 and thisUserGoups is 2
                    if (!thisUserGroups.Contains(userGroup.Group) && (IsInRoleDocAdmin || userGroup.UsrID == usrID))
                        thisUserGroups.Add(userGroup.Group);
                }
            }
            return thisUserGroups;   // docAdmin fail thisUserGroups = 14  
        }
    }

    public User(Int16 UsrIDcon, string UserIDcon, string UserInitialsCon, string IPROuserIDcon, string IPROuserPWcon, Int16? FieldGroupID,
                double WindowLeft, double WindowTop, double WindowHeight, double WindowWidth, bool WindowMaximized,
                bool ViewIpro, bool ViewNative, enumSearchDetail? SearchDetail, string ExportPath)
    {
        usrID = UsrIDcon;
        userID = UserIDcon;
        userInitials = UserInitialsCon;
        iPROuserID = IPROuserIDcon;
        iPROuserPW = IPROuserPWcon;
        fieldGroupID = FieldGroupID;
        windowLeft = WindowLeft;
        windowTop = WindowTop;
        windowHeight = WindowHeight;
        windowWidth = WindowWidth;
        windowMaximixed = WindowMaximized;
        viewIpro = ViewIpro;
        viewNative = ViewNative;
        searchDetail = SearchDetail;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExportPath)) exportPath = ExportPath;
        if (App.StaticGabeLib != null && App.StaticGabeLib.Search != null && searchDetail != null)
        {
            App.StaticGabeLib.Search.SearchDetail = (enumSearchDetail)searchDetail;
        }
        loginTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the class definition for the one that's failing to serialize?

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop Code sample and more detail added

Comment: Does `Group` or one of its children contain a property of type `System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument`?

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop NO  - that is what really confuses me.  What is interesting is if I do the groupsPlus only and not the userGroups then it works.  So it does work with some Groups but not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can figure is that adding from two collections was the problem.

I refactored to only use groupsPlus (no userGroup.Group) and it worked.

But I don't know why that made it work.

What is even more strange is the it used to work adding from two collections.